Is it possible to create a Google Cloud Platform project via REST API without an existent GCP project?
I want to create a Google Cloud Platform project via REST API.
But apparently I can't get OAuth credentials without a first GCP project created, and I want to create a GCP project via REST without having to create another GCP project manually first.
You can create a project via REST via url:
https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v3/projects/create
In the "Try this method" side panel you can create a GCP project via API Explorer OAuth login.
It is possible to create a project there without creating a GCP project first.
The question is, how to create a GCP project like the API Explorer in the URL above?
How to get the OAuth credentials to do that?

How will you run the REST call? In a (Linux) shell using e.g. curl? In a program e.g. Python?

I don't understand where the title of this question comes from, nothing in that api doc says anything about needing a gcp project first. Have you read https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/? If you login with gcloud and a user account it doesn't look like this makes you create a project explicitely. Fwiw Looking at my private google account, it looks like a dummy gcp project is attached to that despite me never doing anything with it, so its quite likely you already have a project to work from as well, if this were needed.

AFAIK, you need a "quota project" to run a request on Google Cloud. However, I'm not sure this API require a quota project. In any case, you won't be able to create a project with a service account, because a service account is a resource, and resource can be only attached to a project. So, the only solution is to use your user account to achieve this. Share the Curl request you perform to allow us to help you on the credential to add.

To proceed using the projects.create method, you will need to use OAuth, which requires a client ID for authentication.
To generate a client ID, you first need to create a new GCP project. Once your GCP project is set up, you can use the client ID with OAuth, which will allow you to use the projects.create method securely.
